# how to find install directory of jetty (when using apt-get)

Tags: ubuntu-10.04

I've installed jetty on a 64-bit ubuntu image running on vm-fusion (on top of Mac os-x lion). How can i find the install directory? Actually, i'd like to find the "webapps" directory so I can insert a war file.
Thanks,

_Ramy

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find all of the owned files and directories of a package using

```
dpkg -L jetty
```